# Scheduled task with parameter laravel

Tags: laravel, process, parameter-passing, scheduled-tasks

in Laravel 5.6 i have a controller that invokes a command through a Process component.

The command run fine, is about a compression of a folder with the name the user gives.

```
$command = 'tar -czvf '.$nameFile.' storage/images/';

$process = new Process($command);
$process->setTimeout(1800);
$process->run();
```

I need to schedule that job 3 times a day. I saw task scheduling with file app/Console/Kernel.php; the problem is to execute the process with the file name the user gives.

How can i programm a Schedule task in this situation?

Thanks

Comment: where the name come from? from cli or user input through user interface?

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: The name comes from a form @Ben

Comment: The problem is, i run that code from a controller so i can give the method the $nameFile parameter; the schedule task run from app/console/kernel.php file and i don't know how can i give it the name of the file, that's my problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Assume you run the schedule tasks three times a day, per each user input. You can create a eloquent model for such purpose, says `ProcessTask`, and save the required data in Controller:

```
ProcessTask::create(['user_id' => $userId, 'name_file' => $nameFile]);
```

Then, you can make scheduling task as:

```
$schedule->call(function () {
    $tasks = ProcessTask::all();
    foreach ($tasks as $task) {
        $command = 'tar -czvf '.$task->name_file.' storage/images/';

        ....
    }
})->hourly()
   ->when(function() { return date('H') % 8 == 0; }) // run tasks at 00:00, 08:00, 16:00
   ->name('processTask')
   ->withoutOverlapping();
```

If the scheduling tasks are time-consuming, the best practice is to dispatch tasks to queue and let workers consume it.

Comment: That seems a good solution, i will to implement it and will tell you how is going, thanks